# analyze the screen and dispatch clicks

Tags: android

I want to make an application that analyzes the color of certain pixel of the screen, and after that click in some places of the screen. The app is running in background, and execute a service to make that. My questions are:

**1 - Analyze the screen:**

I tried to using `/system/bin/screencap -p /sdcard/autoClicker/img.png`, but this solution need root to work, and presents a bad performance (about 3000 ms). I see apps using a native android function , Cast Screen, like a **Pixolor** app. I searched about this function, but don't find anything.

**Print of the app:**
[He show the color of some pixel of the screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flf43.jpg)

**2 - Dispatch on the screen**

I tried use this:

```
MotionEvent keyUp = MotionEvent.obtain(
            downTime,
            eventTime,
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP,
            x,
            y,
            metaState
   );

view.getRootView().dispatchTouchEvent(keyUp);
```

But i don't know how use this on the service. I also tried using this: `/system/bin/input tap x y`, but the same problem of the other question are happening.

I want to make an app with don't need root permissions to run, and a satisfactory performance. Anyone can help me with this?

Comment: You can't.  This kind of thing explicitly needs root to work.

Comment: But some apps can make similar things without root. Like the app I mentioned.

Comment: There is no way to get touch evernts on another app, except in a limited case as an accessibility service.  There is no general way to get access to the screen.  There are purposely no APIs for that for security reasons.

Comment: Sorry for insisting, but can you see the Pixolor app? He does exactly what I need.

Comment: I will put a print of the app in the question.